# Installing help content for VS 2013 fails with "the requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped while installing"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, help-viewer

I'm trying to install help content for VS 2013 and it fails with following message:
[image: Error message]

I have fresh Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 Home. I've tried:

1. Restart
2. Taking ownership on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2\Catalogs
3. Unchecking "Read only" on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2\Catalogs
4. Running Help Viewer from command line as administrator

Nothing helps. Any thoughts? Suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an anti-virus program breaking things.

Comment: Thank you! I've realized it just after posting the question :)

Comment: Please answer your own question and describe how you solved it.

Comment: Just as SLaks mentioned - antivirus blocked the installation. After disabling it everything worked ok.